# MYSQL and PHP loop and grab just one item from a joint table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreach

I am currently building a custom CMS to help me learn PHP and MYSQL. I have two database tables 'users' and 'articles'. When the user submits an article, the field 'author_id' in the 'articles' table places to the users 'users_id' from the 'users' table. This way i can join the tables and get all the articles from that user. Now i am trying to make a feature section on the home page. I want to loop through all authors/users and get one article from that user. Here is a sample of my code...

```
$author= db::getInstance()->query("SELECT * FROM users, articles WHERE user_id = author_id"); 

   foreach($author->results() as $author) {
      echo $author->profile_img;
      echo $author->user_name
      echo $author->article_title; 
   }
```

This works fine if the user has only posted one article but if there are more than 1 then it will loop through all the posts of that user. I just want to echo 1 article from each user but not sure how i can achieve this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Many Thanks,

Louis Lombardi

Comment: Well, either don't loop, or limit your result set.

Comment: ' I just want to echo 1' Which 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MySql `limit`:

```
SELECT * FROM users, articles WHERE user_id = '$author_id' limit 0,1
```

Complete documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: ahhh this is great. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: @Strawberry yes but that's in case if the OP wants to get the latest article displayed. In that case it would be `ORDER BY article_id desc `

Comment: This answer chooses an arbitrary article for a given user.  The question suggests that the article should actually be one where the user is an author.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, I did not get your point. Is there anything wrong with the documentation link I have referred to?

Answer (score 2):

If you want one *arbitrary* article for each user, you can use a MySQL (mis)feature that allows you to do "partial" aggregations:

```
SELECT u.*, a.*
FROM users u JOIN
     articles a
     ON u.user_id = a.author_id
GROUP BY u.user_id;
```

My preferred method for a *random* article would be more like this:

```
select u.*, a.*
from (select u.*,
             (select a.article_id
              from articles a
              where a.author_id = u.user_id
              order by rand()
              limit 1
             ) as article_id
      from users u
     ) u join
     articles a
     on u.article_id = a.article_id;
```

Finally, my preferred method for getting the first/last would look something like this:

```
SELECT u.*, a.*
FROM users u JOIN
     articles a
     ON u.user_id = a.author_id
WHERE a.article_id = (SELECT MAX(a2.article_id)
                      FROM articles a2
                      WHERE a2.author_id = u.author_id
                     );
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this man, much appreciated. Unfortunately someone already beat you to the answer but this is great to know and really really useful!